# What did he mean by saying "giddy up"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I saw a boy riding on another boy yelled proudly to his mount, “So, giddy up!”

What did he mean by saying "giddy up"?

Comment: "Move on!, go faster!" ---- Didn't you try to google? I found the answer in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Giddy up" is a common phrase uttered by cowboys to tell their horses to go faster.

It has a variety of spellings including "[giddyap](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/giddyap)"

> a command (as to a horse) to go ahead or go faster

It's not used much in current language other than referring back to the cowboy era and horseback riding.